# Fix Image Size Irrespective of Browser Zoom and Resolution Changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to fix an image size within a `div`, so it stays the same regardless of browser zoom or resolution changes. Here's the code:

```css
.non-resizable-watermark {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="non-resizable-watermark">
  <img id="watermarkLogoImg" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg" width="120">
</div>
```

Here are the problems I've faced:

- Using `vw` units for the image size makes it responsive to browser width changes, which is not desired.
- Setting the size in `px` keeps it constant during browser resizing, but it scales with browser zoom, which I want to avoid.
- I tried capturing resize events on the window to adjust the image size dynamically, but this didn't work as expected, likely because zooming doesn't trigger a resize event in the way I anticipated:

```js
const initialWidth = window.innerWidth;
const defaultWatermarkLogoWidth = 120;

function adjustLogoSize() {
  const currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const zoomLevel = currentWidth / initialWidth;
  const scaleFactor = 1 / zoomLevel;
  console.log(scaleFactor);

  document.getElementById('watermarkLogoImg').style.width = defaultWatermarkLogoWidth * scaleFactor + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', adjustLogoSize);

adjustLogoSize();
```

```css
.non-resizable-watermark {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="non-resizable-watermark">
  <img id="watermarkLogoImg" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg" width="120">
</div>
```

The image should remain at a fixed size, not affected by changes in browser zoom level or window resizing. How can this be achieved with CSS or JavaScript or both, given the standard behaviour of browsers to scale content? I'm open to creative solutions like using canvas or other techniques, as long as they achieve the desired effect.